# ternary works different in local and heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have this method it's very simple and almost all of the time the isTrue param should be false and return "2".

```
def test(isTrue = false)
  isTrue ? 1 : 2
end
```

this works fine in my dev env but when I push it to heroku suddenly it starts returning as if it is true, and Im absolutly positive that its false. I think it possibly be checking if the var is nil ( or something like that)

I changed the ternary to:

```
isTrue == true ? 1 : 2
```

And it corrects the problem, I don't understand why this happens.
Can someone explain it?
thanks!

Comment: would rather be `isTrue == true`

Comment: That 'fix' will always return 1, because assigning '=' true to isTrye will always be true.

Comment: That was a typo :S sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely wrong:

```
isTrue = true ? 1 : 2
```

It sets the variable `isTrue` to `true` and uses the result of that statement (`true`) as the input of the ternary operator, so this will always return `true`.

Change it to:

```
isTrue == true ? 1 : 2
```

Regarding the differences between development and production mode: check that you really feed booleans into the method and not integers (0 or 1), strings ('0', '1', 't', 'f', 'y', 'n', etc) or nil.

Comment: That was a typo :S sorry

Comment: That makes sense I'm going to log the value and check it. thanks

Comment: You are correct dear sir, what was going on is that the parameter was passed as an url parameter as  "is_true"=>"false" so it would recognize it as string. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
isTrue = true ? 1 : 2
```

this will always return `1` as [Mark Meeus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/459310/mark-meeus) commented.

`=` is the [assignment operator](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Operators#1._Assignment) in ruby, used to make assign a variable a given value.

`==`, however is a [comparison operator](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Comparable.html#method-i-3D-3D).

so with your code as it is currently, you're assigning "isTrue = true" and then telling the code to return `1` if `isTrue` is `true`.

Comment: That was a typo :S sorry